# Tensorflow: How to perform an operation on each element of a matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two matrices A (Nx100) and B (Mx100). I want to perform an operation (say calculate Euclidean distance) for each element in matrix A with each element in matrix B. In normal numpy that would be done using two for loops.

For now, I'm using a map function `tf.map_fn` to map each element in matrix A to the operation where I do `A[i] - B` where A[i] is a vector. This works because TensorFlow broadcasts the vector into the shape of the matrix.

I was wondering if there is a way I can do this more easily. Something like: `tf.do_magic( A, B, operation )`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Euclidean distance of A and B:

```
tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.expand_dims(A, 1) - B)), 2))
```